# Как получить доступ к статическим файлам React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня React App, в нем я настроил с помощью CopyPlugin[image: введите сюда описание изображения] webpack так, что он при сборке загружает в dist в папку dictionaries, несколько файлов словарей в формате JSON.

Ссылок на данные словари внутри кода прилодения нету, но я хотел бы узнать, могу ли я получить доступ к данным файлам в связи событием(например пользователь нажал кнопку сменить язык) и при запуске функции как то подцепить эти словари из dist/dictionaries???[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Именно эту функцию выполняет пакет i18next.
Вы создаете статические JSON файлы со структурой ключ - перевод.
И в зависимости от выбранной локализации подтягивается необходимый JSON с переводами.
Попробуйте - очень удобный и полезный инструмент, которым пользуюсь почти в каждом проекте.